# Import function in node module (alphavantage)

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, alpha-vantage

I'm trying to test out the alphavantage module in Node and it keeps throwing this error:

```
import Util from './lib/util';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1055:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1103:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1159:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:988:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1028:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\thepa\Desktop\FANSchool\FANEconimics\app.js:1:15)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1159:10)
```

File structure:

```
"C:\Users\thepa\Desktop\FANEconimics\app.js"
"C:\Users\thepa\Desktop\FANEconimics\data.json"
"C:\Users\thepa\Desktop\FANEconimics\keys.txt"
"C:\Users\thepa\Desktop\FANEconimics\LICENSE"
"C:\Users\thepa\Desktop\FANEconimics\package.json"
"C:\Users\thepa\Desktop\FANEconimics\package-lock.json"
"C:\Users\thepa\Desktop\FANEconimics\README.md"
"C:\Users\thepa\Desktop\FANEconimics.git"
"C:\Users\thepa\Desktop\FANEconimics\node_modules"
"C:\Users\thepa\Desktop\FANEconimics.gitignore"
```

app.js:

```
const alpha = require("alphavantage")({ key: 'mykey' });

alpha.data.intraday(`msft`).then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

It happens after I run node app.js.
I saw that older versions of node don't support ESM imports, so I updated to the latest version v13.5.0.
also updated npm to v6.13.4

Would this be a problem with the module or my setup?

Comment: Could you add some clarity to this? It seems like your app.js file is unrelated to the issue you're having. Running your app.js code looks ok.

Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import ?

It looks like if you load the source file in the ```src``` directory instead of the built file in the ```dist``` directory, that should fix it.

Comment: There is no src or dist directory, they are all running in the root folder. I edited the post to show the file structure, the import function is in the node_modules folder. Also added what commands I am running too.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63751576/9852497

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, this is a mistake of the library. They are using experimental features without transpiling their code.

My advice is not to use the node package and rather the REST API.

Install fetch to easily consume the API:

```
npm i --save node-fetch
```

Then run something like this:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch")

const base = "https://www.alphavantage.co/"

const apikey = "demo"

const query = (function_name, symbol, interval = "5min") => fetch(
    base + "/query?" + new URLSearchParams({ "function": function_name, symbol, interval, apikey })
)


query("TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY", "MSFT")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
    })
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I'll probably have to contact alphavantage with the issue too to see if they can fix it.

Comment: As far as I can tell the package is not an official AlphaVantage package. Thus they will probably not bother. However I created a PR (https://github.com/zackurben/alphavantage/pull/74) to the package which fixes the issue. Maybe the maintainer will merge it :)